# How to use the tensorflow 2.0 C API?

Tags: c++, xcode, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow in a C++ project in Xcode. I've followed the "Install TensorFlow for C" tutorial found on their web page (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c).

I had to change several fields in the build settings section of my Xcode project to make it work.

1. I added "/usr/local/include" to the Header Search Paths.
2. I added "/usr/local/lib" to the Library Search Paths.
3. I added "-ltensorflow" to the Other Linker Flags.

After doing that, the program correctly compiles and prints : "Hello from TensorFlow C library version 2.4.0". So according to the tutorial, the installation was successful, and I should be able to use the C API.

What I don't understand, is how I can access the API itself. For example how can I declare a variable of type tensorflow::Scope?

According to other tutorials I found online (ex : https://itnext.io/creating-a-tensorflow-dnn-in-c-part-1-54ce69bbd586 ) I should include a files located at `tensorflow/core/framework/...` but I don't have such files on my computer.

Tensorflow says that the entire API is accessible though the single file `tensorflow/c/c_api.h`. But then how can I make something like `using namespace tensorflow;` work?

I've been struggling on that issue for days now and I really hope someone will be able to help me.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, which API do you want to use? You cannot use namespaces in C.

Comment: My project is in C++. On the tensorflow website, it seems that even if my project is in C++ I should access tensorflow using the C API. Is that correct?

Comment: I haven't used TensorFlow in a while, but I remember there being a C++ API.

Answer (score 5):

The example you provided (tensorflow::Scope) can be used with C++ and and not with tensorflow C API. For this kind of instructions, you need to build the tensorflow from source (I found this repo very helpful https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc).

In case you want to use C API then you can call all those functions that you find in c_api.h. For example, the following is my C++ file (hello_tf_cpp.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello from Tensorflow C++ library version " << TF_Version() << std::endl;
  //printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());

  TF_Graph* Graph = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_Status* Status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_SessionOptions* SessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Buffer* RunOpts = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

And this is how I compile and run it:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib hello_tf_cpp.cpp -l tensorflow -o hello_tf_cpp
    $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
    $./hello_tf_cpp

    $ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And this is the output I get:
Hello from Tensorflow C++ library version 1.15.0