# Including TensorFlow into JUCE project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, juce

I am trying to include the TensorFlow C Library in my JUCE project. Until now, with no luck.

When following the TensorFlow guide on how to install the library for C I get lost after the extraction part (developing with Windows). I Add the files inside the include folder to my project using the Projucer. The library with the dll and lib file is added as well. When running Visual Studio, however, there are some includes not inside the provided include folder. My guess is, that I need to link the included library with the full TensorFlow blackened.

Did anyone manage to include TensorFlow inside a JUCE project?

Tutorials I've looked at already:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c

https://forum.juce.com/t/has-anyone-managed-to-integrate-tensorflow-api-in-a-juce-project/28019

[How to use the tensorflow 2.0 C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154351/how-to-use-the-tensorflow-2-0-c-api)

Comment: I'd look for a more general way of embedding python libraries / wrappers in juce. HAve you seen this? https://forum.juce.com/t/loading-pytorch-model-using-binarydata/39997/4

Comment: No, I have not seen this post. This throws another question mark. Can I import the tensorflow model using Pytorch C API?
I stumbled upon cppflow, but I am having problems implementing it. In its header file there are includes of the tensorflow C API using <> bracket notation. I guess I have to add the tensorflow C API into my global path. For mac and Linux there are a lot of resources talking about this. How do I manage to do that using Windows?

Comment: I am a Mac user; you should be aware of additional dll in Windows, but this is very library dependent. I suggested this link as an alternative to tensorflow, pytorch might be wrappable if it is not possible with tensorflow.